# regular expression help for import data in database by array loop

Tags: php, regex

I have a text file where all the question and answer is there like bellow text

```
question l : Regular expression problem in C#  

answer 1 :   regular expression answer 1

question  2 : Regular expression problem in php 

answer 2 :   regular expression answer 2
```

etc...

I made this like bellow

```
<question> question l : Regular expression problem in C# </question> 

<answer> answer 1 : regular expression answer 1</answer>

<--page-->

<question>question 2 : Regular expression problem in php </question>

<answer>answer 2 : regular expression answer 1</answer>

<--page-->
```

So that i can made a array and foreach loop i can insert that to my data base in bellow table

question_id, question answer

1       Regular expression problem in C#    regular expression answer 1

2      Regular expression problem in php   regular expression answer 2

any one can help me to build the regular expression, i build this one but it include question text in answer text

```
preg_match_all("#^(?<!<question>).*<question>.*?</question>(?!.*<question>)#",$temp_data,$question);
preg_match_all("#^(?<!<answer>).*<answer>.*?</answer>(?!.*<answer>)#",$temp_data,$answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I can completely follow, but I think you wanted this

```
preg_match_all("#(?<=<question>).*?(?=</question>)#",$temp_data,$question);
preg_match_all("#(?<=<answer>).*?(?=</answer>)#",$temp_data,$answer);
```

The first one would match anything between a `<question>` tag and the next `</question>` tag, but not the tags itself. See [it on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30vj9)

The second would match anything between a `<answer>` tag and the next `</answer>` tag, but not the tags itself.

Comment: yes i want to get text all inside <question> tags </question> tag